# How to display data from another on UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am working on a winforms application that plots live data from a tcp/ip connection. I am taking input from a thread (let's say input thread) and storing it as a .csv file which is then used to plot the graph with a button press and am able to do so.

I am having a problem with showing messages on a listbox about the input data I am getting from the input thread. As the listbox is in the UI thread, I am not able to access it from the input thread.

So how can I show messages on listbox from the input thread?

```
public void input()
{
    myTimer.Interval = Int32.Parse(sampleRatetxt.Text);//taking input in  milliseconds
    myTimer.Elapsed += TimerEventProcessor;
    myTimer.Start();
}

private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    byte[] ba = new byte[52];
    int num = 0;
    {
        NetworkStream stm = tcpclient.GetStream();
        if (stm.DataAvailable)
        {
            num = stm.Read(ba);
            loglistbox.Items.Add("bytes read: " + num);    //cant access listbox                                                      
            string datastring = Convert.ToHexString(ba);
            loglistbox.Items.Add("recived string: " + datastring);     //cant access listbox                                           
            DataPacket packetNew = new DataPacket(datastring);
            loglstbx.Items.Add("recived single packet: " + packetNew.dataPacket);                               //cant access listbox
            loglstbx.Items.Add("frame Length=" + packetNew.frameLength + " | frame ID=" + packetNew.frameID);   //cant access listbox
            loglstbx.Items.Add("val1: " + packetNew.val[0] + "   val2: " + packetNew.val[1]);                    //cant access listbox
            loglstbx.Items.Add("val3: " + packetNew.val[2] + "  val4: " + packetNew.val[3]);                     //cant access listbox
                                                                                                                 //passes the data recieved only if frame Id matches
            if (packetNew.frameID == Int32.Parse(serverIDtxt.Text)) ;
            rawSeries1 = packetNew.val;
            stm.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer to "how to display data from another thread" is to use `BeginInvoke` to marshal the data back onto the UI thread before setting any properties on any UI control. This [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) leaves out the `TcpClient` code in order to focus on the question at hand.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        input();
    }
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public void input()
    {
        myTimer.Interval = 500; // Value for test
        myTimer.Elapsed += TimerEventProcessor;
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        loglistbox.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            loglistbox.Items.Add("received single packet: ");
            loglistbox.Items.Add($"frame Length = {_rando.Next(10, 21)}");
        });
    }
    // Test data
    Random _rando = new Random(1);
}
```

[image: screenshot]